# MOQ mocking an interface with setter injection

Tags: c#, testing, nunit, moq

Please the below code snippet

```
public class FileUploadPresenter
{
    private IFileRepository FileRepository
    {
        get { return UnityManager.Resolve<IFileRepository>(); }
    }
    public void LoadData(int id)
    {
         //How can I redirect the below ReadData call to Mocked method in the testcase ?bypassing the FileRepository getter ?
         List<FileModel> fileModelList = FileRepository.ReadData(Id);
        //Do something with the data
    }
}
```

My unit test case

```
[TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<IFileRepository>();
        FileModelfm = new FileModel();
        fm.FileId = 1;
        fm.FileName = "abc";
        fm.PolicyTxnId = 10;
        List<FileModel> fml = new List<FileModel>();
        fml.Add(fm);
        mock.Setup(item => item.ReadData(10)).Returns(fml);        
        FileUploadPresenter FileUploadPresenterobj = new FileUploadPresenter();
        obj.LoadData();
    }
```

Here my mocking code is not really working .How can I setup a mock such a way that the interface method call from my invoking class will hit the mocked method ? Here my interface property is private and readonly .

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to register your mocked instance with `UnityManager`. The mocked instance is stored in the `Object` property of your mock.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var mock = new Mock<IFileRepository>();
    UnityManager.RegisterInstance<IFileRepository>(mock.Object);

    // ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using the UnityManager in this manner. Your IFileRepository is a dependency, it should be **injected** into your FileUploadPresenter.

What you've implemented here is a service locator pattern, which as a result has made it hard to test.

If you change your FileUploadPresenter to have a constructor that takes an IFileRepository. You can then mock up an IFileRepository for the test.